# Login prompt no longer on external display

Tags: boot, login, multiple-monitors, display

Been experimenting with Ubuntu on my Toshiba Satellite U500. Using an external display (AOC 23" LCD) as primary.

For the first 20 or so boots, the Ubuntu 15.04 login prompt appeared on my external display exactly where you'd want it.

Suddenly, now, it only appears on the laptop screen. The external display does come on and shows the Ubuntu wallpaper. But I have to get up and walk over to the laptop to login. Then Ubuntu finishes booting to the proper desktop on my external display.

This is a big pain in the ass. I've done a repair reinstallation - not wiping everything, but reinstalling from USB. Hasn't fixed it. No luck searching here through other threads.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have pam-mount? Or other configuration? Try:
PS1="\s-\v\$"
If it works try:
Open /etc/bashrc (Redhat and friends) / or /etc/bash.bashrc (Debian/Ubuntu) or /etc/bash.bashrc.local (Suse and others) file and append following code:

## vi /etc/bashrc

or
$ sudo gedit /etc/bashrc

Append the code as follows

## If id command returns zero, you’ve root access.

if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ];
then # you are root, set red colour prompt
  PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\u@\h:\w #\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
else # normal
  PS1="[\u@\h:\w] $"
fi
Close and save the file.

Source

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: You might have been trying to answer somebody else's question. Your info appears to be about changing terminal window appearance (?). I'm just trying to get the login on the external display.